# How to covert an array of images to anyobject with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsarray

I have an array of images and i want to covert them all to an anyObject object. How do i do this all at the same time and not one array index at a time?

Code...

```
var imageArray:[UIImage] = [Image1, Image2, Image3]

let convertImage:[AnyObject] = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageArray)
```

Comment: `imageArray.map { UIImagePNGRepresentation($0) as AnyObject }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dataArray:[AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
for image in imageArray {
    dataArray.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image))
}
```

Or, to steal from @Airspeed Velocity's comment:

```
let dataArray = imageArray.map { UIImagePNGRepresentation($0) as AnyObject }
```

This has the nice advantage of letting us declare the data array as a `let` constant rather than a `var`.